# Support "View Value in Data Viewer" for custom class

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, vscode-python

In the VSCode Python debugger, I can right-click on numpy array or pandas DataFrame and select "View Value in Data Viewer". Is it possible to support this for a self-implemented class?

I first tried to sublass collections.abc.Sequence, which does not work. I then tried to sublass np.ndarray, but that didn't work either. Is there some magic dust I can implement?

```
from collections.abc import Sequence
import numpy as np

class X(Sequence):
    _x: np.ndarray

    def __init__(self, x: np.ndarray):
        self._x = x

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self._x[index]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._x)

    def __contains__(self, value):
        return value in self._x

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._x)

class Y(np.ndarray):
    pass

an_array = np.array([1, 2, 3])   # menu available
an_instance_of_X = X(an_array)   # not
an_instance_of_Y = Y(an_array)   # not

print("Break here")
```

Comment: How about using [composition over inheritance](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance), so the custom class has an attribute that you can view in the Data Viewer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Jupyter-Notebook](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-toolsai.jupyter).

It support you to check variables by clicking this button:

[image]

In your case, it'll show:

[image]